# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory error

Tags: mysql

There has been an error processing your request

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Getting the above error please someone provide me solution to solve this.

Comment: I've fixed it by changing connection string, make sure that your mysql is on and you have all the tables exists in the database.

Answer (score 35):

I had the same issue while installing Magento 2.1.0 with PHP 7.0.13. 
 I could resolve this issue by setting the database **hostname** as **127.0.0.1** instead of **localhost** .

Comment: Where should this be done?

Comment: inside ./app/etc/env.php

Comment: This worked for me, Thank you.

Comment: Works for me, thanks!

Answer (score 11):

If your server listed in `app/etc/local.xml` is `localhost` and this error appears in Magento's error log, but Magento still is running ok, then mysql was restarted and the socket `/tmp/mysql.sock` or whatever socket file is set up in `my.cnf` temporarily disappeared.

Because it's missing, the PDO mysql connector reports `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory`

If you are continually getting this error thrown and have no access to Magento aside from the Exception Error page, then mysql has crashed completely and you need your hosting provider to find out why and restart mysql.

Answer (score 8):

This seems to be wrong PHP version issue, you need to select which php have to use to run the command as follows:

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.20/bin/php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

PS: Above sample is for MAC, you can do it similar way for windows or unix as well.

Comment: Great! it is also workable for me.

Answer (score 7):

set the database hostname as 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost.

Answer (score 2):

This can also happen if ur filesystem is full ...
df -h 1st ...ofcourse, mostly u shud get alerts before that...

mysqld wont be running normally, and would be in a "safe" mode

HTH
SNS

Answer (score 2):

You have to change the hostname from localhost to 127.0.0.1 in env configuration file in your magento root directory

- Open app/etc/env.php
- change 'host' => 'localhost' to 'host' =>'127.0.0.1'
- Save file and retry

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue, and I used below to select which php have to use. `/usr/local/etc/php/7.2/bin/php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

See official docs:
[SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/trouble/php/tshoot_phpini.html)

Answer (score 1):

for mac machine I have used this command and it will work

```
ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you edit your **app/etc/local.xml** properly.
If you have no prefixes for your tables make sure the proper line is:

```
<table_prefix><![CDATA[]]></table_prefix>
```

NOT

```
<table_prefix>{{db_prefix}}</table_prefix>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is commonly caused by a different instance of PHP being used by the PHP command line compared to the web server. In particular, `mysql.sock` might be misconfigured if this is the case.

To determine whether or not you’re using one instance of PHP:

1. Log in to your Magento server.
2. Enter the following command:

   ```
   php -i | grep 'php.ini'
   ```

This determines the settings used by the PHP command-line interface (CLI). Note where `php.ini` is located.

3. If you haven’t already done so, set up a `phpinfo.php` on your web server.
4. Compare the value of **Loaded Configuration File** from `phpinfo.php` with the one from `php -i`.

`phpinfo.php` shows the `php.ini` file used by your web server. If it’s different from what's in PHP's `php.ini`, you must make all PHP settings consistent for both the PHP CLI and the web server.

For additional details, consult the documentation provided with your web server.

Comment: This can happen - I think I am facing this right now. But why? Any specific ideas on what to check in these ini files?

Comment: Rather You may provide some courtesy to this page http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/trouble/php/tshoot_phpini.html

Answer (score 0):

I have several versions of PHP available to me via the shell - typing **php** and pressing tab shows which ones my autocomplete knows about.

For me, PHP 5.4, 5.5 and 5.6 were all working fine, but PHP 7 wasn't finding the mysql.sock, and was crashing with the **"SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory error"** discussed in this question.

```
# Prints [ok]
echo "<?php print(new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'mysql') ? '[ok]' : '[error]').PHP_EOL; ?>" | php-5.6.20

# Prints [error] and shows a warning
echo "<?php print(new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'mysql') ? '[ok]' : '[error]').PHP_EOL; ?>" | php-7.0.8
```

To see where your mysql server has its socket, use this command:

```
cat /etc/mysql/my.cnf | grep socket
```

In my case, with Percona Mysql installed in my vagrant system the sock socket file happened to live here:

```
/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

(notice that it is called **mysqld** not simply **mysql**)

I have several versions of php to choose from and these commands showed me which ones had issues and which ones were fine:

The answer for me was simply to include code in the vagrant provisioner script to create a symlink between /tmp/mysql.sock and /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

```
if [ ! -L /tmp/mysql.sock ]; then
    echo "Creating symbolic link for php 7 to connect to mysql.sock"
    ln -s /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock /tmp/mysql.sock
fi
```

With the new symlink in place, the test script given before now works perfectly for all versions of PHP and I can use **localhost** in my code instead of having to give the **127.0.0.1** IP address.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory". And found that MySQL service was stopped. I started my MySQL service and its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am using linux, run following commands.

```
/opt/lampp/bin/php  bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

And Working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your Server Setup, look in your tmp/mysql folder and you may find a mysql.sock.lock file.
You can safely remove this file and try your command again

Answer (score 0):

Just try restarting the MySql

```
service mysql start
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while installing Magento 2.3.5 with PHP 7.3.33.
I could resolve this issue by setting the database hostname as mysql instead of localhost.

Note : I am using docker with mysql container.

Answer (score -1):

just clean your cache it will work

bin/magento ca:cl && chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/