# PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory error fixed, but now website is very slow / unresponsive

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.4

Before the fix, I tried to install the [printful module](https://www.printful.com/dashboard/connect/magento), got through to Step 3 to where you enable the module and paused half way through execution. The front or back-end wasn't loading and after ages of trying to load it, it gave me this error on my browser:

[image: error]

I followed [this link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/51948/sqlstatehy000-2002-no-such-file-or-directory-error) on fixing this error, changing localhost to 127.0.0.1. This worked, as I can log in to the back-end and the front-end loads but is taking forever to load to the next page that I navigate to, sometimes so long that it times the admin account out and goes back to the login.

I've allocated 2G in the PHP memory_limit, but when I go to `bin/magento c:c`
I get this error:

```
mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory
PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 10485760) (tried to allocate 12288 bytes) in /var/www/html/vendor/zendframework/zend-uri/src/Uri.php on line 1024
```

I am so confused.

Comment: `php -d memory_limit=5G bin/magento c:c` run this command

Answer (score 0):

You could resolve this issue by setting the database `hostname` as `127.0.0.1` instead of localhost . In your `/app/etc/env.php` file.

Second you logout automatically.I think your magento account problem .So you new create `username` and `password`.So you go to `Stores → Configuration` and open `Advanced → Admin → Security`. By default, Magento has the session time around 900 seconds which is around 15 minutes but you can increase this easily with any number you want.

For example, you can double this session time to 1800 so the Admin Session Lifetime is around 30 minutes. Change the setting and Save the Config to save the changes.

And third your problem run this command :- `php -d memory_limit=5G bin/magento c:c`

Hope help you

Thanks...